# Memory Monitoring in Apache Ignite

Tags: memory, ignite, metrics

> I am using Apache Ignite 2.8.0.
>   i am running my server without persistence.
>   i have some records in my cache. it shows "totalAllocatedSize":18869600.
>   Now i cleared my cache, again it shows as the same "totalAllocatedSize":18869600.(i don't have any records in my cache)
>   why it shows like this, actually i don't have any records in cache, so it need to be show as 0. but it shows the previous value i got when some records in my cache.. 
>   why it's behave like this? or How i will get my actual memory used right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many databases, Apache Ignite will not de-allocate memory it has already allocated. You can see that you have space available by decreased `fillFactor` metric.

Comment: Actually i have set my maxSize as 20Mib. with that 20Mib i have to work with lots of data. Now my memory full 19/20. (i have added expiry policy as 1 seconds.). After few seconds i am trying to put some value , now i got outofmoemory Exception. but i don't have any records at the time..  is there any way to make free that space?

Comment: 20M is way too few. I recommend setting it to 100M, since Apache Ignite is not tested with values smaller than that. Also, it will make sense to decrease number of partitions (default 1024, decrease it 10-20fold)

Comment: ok.. fine .. but how i get back those memory after some times?

Comment: You can add more data again and it will use that memory again.